# VCF Contacts Sync like ICS calendars

Tags: synchronization, remote-access, vcf-vcard

Both ICS and VCF are used in **WebDAV** Standard. However, it's possible to **sync ICS** calendars without login/password. Google Calendar, ICSx5, Thunderbird and much more can read .ics remote files.

Is there a way to sync a **remote .vcf address book** without importing it into an existing address book? Or is it to create?